# How to pull data with ETL stored procedure using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, etl, data-warehouse, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In my old database, there is a table `Album` which stores information about ID, AlbumName, Release_Date (e.g. 01/01/2017) etc.

[image]

I want to further break down the `Release_Date` into a time dimension table, so I create a `DimDateAlbum` table.

This is the time dimension table I have created.

```
CREATE TABLE [DimDateAlbum]
(
    [DateKey] INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    [Date] DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [Year] INT NOT NULL,
    [Quarter] TINYINT NOT NULL, 
    [QuarterName] VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL, -- January to March: First, April to 
        June: Second etc
    [Month] TINYINT NOT NULL,
    [MonthName] VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL, -- January, February etc
    [Day] TINYINT NOT NULL, -- Field holds day number of Month
    [DayofWeek] TINYINT NOT NULL, 
    [WeekName] VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL, -- Field displays 1: Monday, 2: Tuesday etc 
)
```

As discussed below: I can insert `Release_Date` into time dimension table as `[DateKey]`, however, how do I further break down the date into year, quarter, day etc.?

```
INSERT INTO DimDateAlbum
    SELECT 
        a.Release_Date AS [DateKey],
        CONVERT (char(8), a.Release_Date, 112) AS [DateKey],
        a.Release_Date AS [Date],
        DATEPART(YEAR, a.Release_Date) AS [Year], -- calendar year
        DATEPART(QQ, a.Release_Date) AS [Quarter], -- calendar quarter
        CASE (qq, a.Release_Date) 
           WHEN 1 THEN 'First' 
           WHEN 2 THEN 'Second' 
           WHEN 3 THEN 'Third' 
           WHEN 4 THEN 'Fourth' 
        END AS [QuarterName], 
        DATEPART(MONTH, a.Release_Date) AS [Month], -- month number of the year
        DATENAME(MM, a.Release_Date) AS [MonthName], -- month name
        DATEPART(DAY, a.Release_Date) AS [Day],  -- day number of the month
        DATEPART(DW, a.Release_Date) AS [DayofWeek], -- day number of week 
        CASE datepart(DW, a.Release_Date)  
           WHEN 1 THEN 'Monday' 
           WHEN 2 THEN 'Tuesday' 
           WHEN 3 THEN 'Wednesday' 
           WHEN 4 THEN 'Thursday' 
           WHEN 5 THEN 'Friday' 
           WHEN 6 THEN 'Saturday' 
           WHEN 7 THEN 'Sunday'
        END AS [WeekName]
    FROM 
        dbo.Album AS a
```

This code does not work, any help on how to fix it? Thank you so much!

Comment: What you mean wtih pulling release_date ? I couln't see release_date at your procedure.

Comment: I just paste a photo in there. What I meant is that I want to break down the Album(Release_Date) DATETIME into a year, quarter, month, week etc. 
But, I don't know how to extract all data from the Release_Date column and insert into DimDateAlbum. E.g., the first one 2017-10-17 should be:

DateKey:20171017, Date  Year: 2017, Quarter: 4, QuarterName : Forth, etc...

Comment: Why do you want to use integer [DateKey] while you already have your release_date as date? You should do absolutely nothing, yor fact table ALREADY can be joined to time dimension on Release_Date = [Date]

Comment: Do you mean that I do not have to create any ETL stored procedure? Sorry, I am new to the ETL thing so I am quite confused as there is no data in the time dimension table so I have to pull data from Album first..

Comment: All you need is to load your dimension table with the data, i.e. you should generate calendar for some years. You should not touch your fact table at all, DateTime dimension is not dependent ot it, it just contains every day for some period of time. And then the fact table is just joined to your datetime dimension

Comment: Like a simple `INSERT INTO DimDateAlbum SELECT Release_Date From dbo.Album`? But how do I break the release_date into year, quarter, and day?

Comment: You should not break nothing. You create your Calendar and then join your table to it. And in every row of the resultset you'll see year, quarter and day, this is the sense of creating DateTime dim

Comment: Take a look on this: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/

Comment: This is very helpful! I am able to make it works. Thanks for explaining everything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your correctly you want to populate `DimDateAlbum` table. I've edited a little bit your table( added identity constraint to avoid writing this field manually) and now it looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [DimDateAlbum]
(
    [DateKey] INT IDENTITY CONSTRAINT PK_DimDateAlbum_ID PRIMARY KEY, 
    [Date] DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [Year] INT NOT NULL,
    [Quarter] TINYINT NOT NULL, 
    [QuarterName] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, -- January to March: First, April to 
    [Month] TINYINT NOT NULL,
    [MonthName] VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL, -- January, February etc
    [Day] TINYINT NOT NULL, -- Field holds day number of Month
    [DayofWeek] TINYINT NOT NULL, 
    [WeekName] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, -- Field displays 1: Monday, 2: Tuesday etc 
)
```

And now you can insert your data. I've added a test variable to insert one row, however it can be used for inserting from table:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.DimDateAlbum
(   
    DateKey, 
    Date,
    Year,
    Quarter,
    QuarterName,
    Month,
    MonthName,
    Day,
    DayofWeek,
    WeekName
)
SELECT     
         CAST(a.Release_Date AS DATETIME)
       , YEAR(CAST(a.Release_Date AS DATETIME)) --        
       ,  DATEPART(QUARTER, CAST(a.Release_Date AS DATETIME)) -- Quarter
       , CASE -- Quarter Name
            WHEN DATEPART(QUARTER, CAST(a.Release_Date AS DATETIME)) = 1 THEN 'January to March' -- Quarter Name
            WHEN DATEPART(QUARTER, CAST(a.Release_Date AS DATETIME)) = 2 THEN 'April to June' -- Quarter Name
            WHEN DATEPART(QUARTER, CAST(a.Release_Date AS DATETIME)) = 3 THEN 'July to September' -- Quarter Name
            WHEN DATEPART(QUARTER, CAST(a.Release_Date AS DATETIME)) = 4 THEN 'October to December' -- Quarter Name
        END
        , MONTH(CAST(a.Release_Date AS DATETIME)) -- Month number
        , DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD( MONTH, MONTH(CAST(a.Release_Date AS DATETIME)), 0) - 1) -- Month name        
        , DAY(CAST(a.Release_Date AS DATETIME)) -- 6
        , DATEPART(dw, CAST(a.Release_Date AS DATETIME)) -- 5
        , DATENAME(dw, CAST(a.Release_Date AS DATETIME)) -- Thursday
FROM Album a
```

Work example:

```
DECLARE @FooDate VARCHAR(30) = '2018-12-06 12:10:51.727'
INSERT INTO dbo.DimDateAlbum
(   
    DateKey, 
    Date,
    Year,
    Quarter,
    QuarterName,
    Month,
    MonthName,
    Day,
    DayofWeek,
    WeekName
)
SELECT     
         CAST(@FooDate AS DATETIME)
       , YEAR(CAST(@FooDate AS DATETIME)) --        
       ,  DATEPART(QUARTER, CAST(@FooDate AS DATETIME)) -- Quarter
       , CASE -- Quarter Name
            WHEN DATEPART(QUARTER, CAST(@FooDate AS DATETIME)) = 1 THEN 'January to March' -- Quarter Name
            WHEN DATEPART(QUARTER, CAST(@FooDate AS DATETIME)) = 2 THEN 'April to June' -- Quarter Name
            WHEN DATEPART(QUARTER, CAST(@FooDate AS DATETIME)) = 3 THEN 'July to September' -- Quarter Name
            WHEN DATEPART(QUARTER, CAST(@FooDate AS DATETIME)) = 4 THEN 'October to December' -- Quarter Name
        END
        , MONTH(CAST(@FooDate AS DATETIME)) -- Month number
        , DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD( MONTH, MONTH(CAST(@FooDate AS DATETIME)), 0) - 1) -- Month name
        , DAY(CAST(@FooDate AS DATETIME)) -- 6
        , DATEPART(dw, CAST(@FooDate AS DATETIME)) -- 5
        , DATENAME(dw, CAST(@FooDate AS DATETIME)) -- Thursday
```